# Why voltage is needed to calculate watt?

Tags: voltage, amperage, watts

I am not sure what is the difference between voltage ampere and watts.
voltage is only the potential difference between points, higher voltage will not cause to the electrons to move faster.
So why the voltage is needed for electrical component specs?

If I have a LED that says 5v and `20mA` for example, why it's needed to write the `5v` if the Ampere is the final result of the volt, does it be matter if the source is `10v` and the resistance grows so the LED still gets only `20mA` at the end?

Comment: Do you think the same about force and speed in power calculations? Or torque and RPM?

Answer (score 3):

> high voltage will not cause to the electrons to move faster

Voltage does cause electrons to move, and all else being equal, higher voltage causes electrons to move faster.

If you could put a Coulomb of electric charge* into an electric field of one volt per meter, then there would be a 1 Newton force between the field and the charge.  If you pushed that charge one meter into the direction of the field, you would have put 1 Joule of potential energy into it -- and the voltage would have changed by one volt.  If you did all that in one second, then you would have had a one Ampere current across a one volt gain -- and you would have exerted one Joule in one second.  So your one Joule in one second is a Watt of power, and your one Ampere across one volt is, again, a watt of power.

Comment: Just a note. It doesn't matter how far apart the plates might be. If you have 1 V of potential difference between them, then one Coulomb of charge will yield 1 Joule of energy upon impact (in a vacuum.) They accelerate slower if the distance is further, but the final velocity is always the same. *Distance* is not a part of "Joules per Coulomb" definition of a volt. (You know this. I'm just mentioning it, in case your wording might not be clear enough on this point.)

Answer (score 1):

Voltage (units in Volts) is the amount of "force" required to push those electrons across the wire. Current (units in Amperes) is the rate at which those electrons flow. Power (units in Watts) is the amount of energy produced at a given amount of rate of electron flow. Here's a familiar cartoon that kind of gives you a visual representation:

[image]

Voltage is defined as potential energy per charge. Current is defined as the amount of charge per time unit. Wattage is defined as potential energy per time unit.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt):

> In terms of electromagnetism, one watt is the rate at which electrical
>   work is performed when a current of one ampere (A) flows across an
>   electrical potential difference of one volt (V), meaning the watt is
>   equivalent to the volt-ampere (the latter unit, however, is used for a
>   different quantity from the real power of an electrical circuit).

When in doubt, use [water analogies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) :)